# HowTo Clear Cache/Memory of Monitors in XP

Tags: windows-xp, external-display

I want to clear the cache/memory of monitors that I've connected to an XP machine. I'm developing a monitor-like device with its own EDID, and I want to see what a "first birthday" is like. However, the machine in question remembers the device and what resolution it's set to, etc.

Comment: Does this belong on StackOverflow?

Comment: sounds like SO material to me.

Comment: Well, the EDID stuff might be, but I thought this was more of a Windows admin question.

Comment: I don't think you can do that in the Windows UI.

Comment: it sounds almost like you want a kernel debugger on a fresh install of Windows (checked version). (...and maybe a DVI protocol analyzer.)  then plug in some new monitor device and record what happens in the debugger.  if you miss it, re-image the test machine and go again.  i recommended SO because this smells to me like OS/kernel/hardware debugging with a touch of reverse engineering.